# What is the swift method equivalent to getConstraintForFirstItem in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nslayoutconstraint

Earlier I have used `getConstraintForFirstItem` to retrieve particular constraints in Objective-C like

```
[[self.superview constraints] getConstraintForFirstItem:self andFirstAttributeis:NSLayoutAttributeBottom];
```

But cannot find equivalent method in swift to retrieve it and it says `Value of type '[NSLayoutConstraint]' has no member 'getConstraintForFirstItem'`. Any solution for this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that `getConstraintForFirstItem` is part of `UIKit`? Maybe this function is from some framework?

Comment: @SIlvester oops. Sorry it is. I will delete this question.

Comment: View the online documentation for the Objective-C method that you know. Then switch the documentation to Swift and you will see the correct method signature.

Answer (score 1):

try this

You can use the firstItem,  secondItem properties of [NSLayoutConstraint] to get the views related to the constraint.

```
let  getConstraints =  self.view.superview!.constraints
        for constraint in getConstraints {
            if let getFirstItem = constraint.firstItem, getFirstItem.firstAttribute == NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom{
           break
        }
      }
```

Comment: customize and try once, if you not get the answer ,plz inform I will delete my answer